# c# why min and max methods doesn't work correctly

Tags: c#, methods, max, min

got .txt file :

```
pasaulyje jau nuo XVI a. pradžios. Lorem Ipsu
atsitiktine tvarka išdėliojo raides aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaa
atspaudų prese ir
qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
```

and here is my code snippet:

```
string max = tekstas.Max();
string min = tekstas.Min();

Console.WriteLine(max);
Console.WriteLine(min);
```

Why  does Max() method give's me the last line(as it would be a shortest, which is actually not) and Min() method give's second line , which would be correct If I would ask with Max method... so what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: what type is variable tekstas ?

Comment: How you define "max" and "min". I guess it uses alphabetical order for the first letter.

Comment: @earloc , string type

Comment: nevermind, see the two valid answers ;)

Comment: @earloc yea , still thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Min and Max on a String use Alphabetic sorting... so this behavior is expected.

If you want to get the max and min by length you could do something like;

```
string maxLength = tekstas.Select(s => s.Length).Max();
string minLength = tekstas.Select(s => s.Length).Min();

string maxString = tekstas.First(s => s.Length == maxLength);
string minString = tekstas.First(s => s.Length == minLength);

Console.WriteLine(maxString );
Console.WriteLine(minString );
```

Comment: thanks mate , finally got the answer , so min and max method I should be using better when looking for words in line ? or even letters in words ? but not for the longest line ?

Comment: Min and Max work on whatever data type you call them on, so if you use on a string (i.e. a line of text or word of text), it will sort alphabetically and return highest (closest to Z) or lowest (closest to A). If you use on a number (like the LENGTH of the strings) then it will return the lowest/highest number. You then need to find the string with that length, since it returns the number (the length)

Comment: appreciate the effort :) will press as a correct answer , when I can

Answer (score 2):

If `Length` is the criteria for Min or Max you can do

```
var max = tekstas.Max(x => x.Length);
var min = tekstas.Min(x => x.Length);

var maxLengthString = tekstas.Where(x => x.Length == max);
var minLengthString = tekstas.Where(x => x.Length == min);
```

Though you can do some refactoring on it like to get First occurrence, you need `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: This would return the size, not the string itself, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Pikoh: Thanks for that.

Comment: Welcome. Now it's just fine :)